# Eclipse on MacOS: SWT lib code signature not valid for use in process using Library Validation

Tags: eclipse, macos, swt

I am trying to run an Eclipse (Oomph 2018.12) based application on MacOS Mojave, and it failed to run as it failed to load `libswt-cocoa` due to missing code signature:

```
    /Users/myuser/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4919.jnilib: dlopen(/Users/myuser/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4919.jnilib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/myuser/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4919.jnilib: code signature in (/Users/myuser/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4919.jnilib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
```

I tried to sign the file ad-hoc, then I got a different error message:

```
    /Users/myuser/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4919.jnilib: code signature in (/Users/myuser/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4919.jnilib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)
```

Ideally I don't want to sign it as it's not my file. Is there a way to disable the library validation for SWT lib on MacOS? If not, how can I sign it properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Checking code signatures is a function of [Gatekeeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatekeeper_(macOS))

```sh
$ sudo spctl --status
$ sudo spctl --master-disable
$ sudo spctl --master-enable
```

Check the status, disable and re-enable, respectively.

See [Technical Note TN2206](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html) for information on code signing if you decide to go that route.